# AND NOT LIKE doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I check for `not like <<something>>` in mysql?

I've tried the following, but the result is always empty:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29a97/1

```
SELECT * 
FROM convertList 
WHERE server='1' and converting not like '%1%' 
ORDER BY important DESC
```

also tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   convertlist 
WHERE  server = '1' 
       AND NOT converting LIKE '%1%' 
ORDER  BY important DESC
```

ps

the list is 100% not empty, I should have at least 10 results.

[image]
[image]

I'm using percona mysql 5.6.

Comment: If you dont use wildcards, like is equivalent to =.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f44790/1

Maybe your simplification of the query masks the problem.

Edit: so I was ALMOST right, your simplification of the DATA was the problem... you have NULLs:

```
SELECT * FROM convertList WHERE server='1' 
and ( converting not like '%1%' OR converting IS NULL)
ORDER BY important
```

NULL is not like any value, and it's not UNlike any value.... it the the lack of a value.

Here is an update SQLfiddle working with NULLs and 1s, thanks to @Orlo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/628e0/1

Comment: @Orlo Yup that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead try

```
not converting like '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

field not like '1' is basically the same as field != 1 ... maybe field not like '%1%' ? (field does not contain "1") ?